# Is there a step-by-step combat flowchart for L5R, 2e?

Tags: combat, l5r-2e

OK, so I played Legend of the Five Rings (2nd edition) years ago and enjoyed it.
When asked what he wanted for a present he replied: "an rpg campaign! But it should be different, not one of the one's I've played so far!" So I figured L5R should be different enough and easy enough.. I had a blast, had the best story ever and we basically only used d10s.
We tried a one shot right away and I realized I needed more of a refresher course than I expected especially since the rules aren't clearly written out.

Is there any place where the full process of combat is clearly stated? From initiative to any sort of bonus for rolling a 20.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming we're talking about the L5R Roll and Keep system, about the closest you will get is the summary on p160 of the 2nd ed Player's Guide - it's not very detailed, but tells you what to do at a very high level.

About the only other help is the Example of Play on p186, which runs through some combat among other things.